# How is Throwable.getSuppressed() supported from Android API 31

Tags: java, android

When testing a code that does nasty reflective operations on Throwable fields, then it is failing on Android API 31. The reason is that `Throwable.suppressedExceptions` field is no longer present.

I did more tests between Android API 30 and 31:

```java
public class ThrowableInternalTest {

  private static final String TAG = "ThrowableInternal";

  @Test
  public void suppressedExceptionsFieldIsPresent() throws Exception {
    Log.w(TAG, "Android API: " + VERSION.SDK_INT);

    // Checking internal fields
    Field[] fields = Throwable.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String fieldNames = Stream.of(fields).map(Field::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    Log.w(TAG, "Throwable fields: " + fieldNames);

    // Manually setting suppressed exceptions
    Exception suppressed = new Exception();
    Exception exception = new Exception();
    exception.addSuppressed(suppressed);
    Log.w(TAG, "exception.getSuppressed(): " + exception.getSuppressed().length);

    // Using try-with-resource block which should have suppressed exceptions
    try {
      try (ThrowingClosable ignored = new ThrowingClosable()) {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      Log.w(TAG, "try-with-resource suppressed: " + t.getSuppressed().length);
    }

    // Results:

    // minSdkVersion: 18
    // Android API: 30
    // Throwable fields: backtrace,cause,detailMessage,stackTrace,suppressedExceptions,serialVersionUID
    // exception.getSuppressed(): 0
    // try-with-resource suppressed: 0

    // minSdkVersion: 19
    // Android API: 30
    // Throwable fields: backtrace,cause,detailMessage,stackTrace,suppressedExceptions,serialVersionUID
    // exception.getSuppressed(): 1
    // try-with-resource suppressed: 1

    // minSdkVersion: 18
    // Android API: 31
    // Throwable fields: backtrace,cause,detailMessage,stackTrace,serialVersionUID
    // exception.getSuppressed(): 0
    // try-with-resource suppressed: 0

    // minSdkVersion: 19
    // Android API: 31
    // Throwable fields: backtrace,cause,detailMessage,stackTrace,serialVersionUID
    // exception.getSuppressed(): 1
    // try-with-resource suppressed:1
  }

  private static class ThrowingClosable implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

When `minSdkVersion` is below 19, then `Throwable.getSuppressed()` always returns an empty array. With higher `minSdkVersion`, then it is working properly.

Although, the `suppressedExceptions` field is only present on API 30, not on 31.
But in the Android SDK source code, the `suppressedExceptions` field is present on both API: [30](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-30/blob/master/java/lang/Throwable.java#L239) and [31](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-31/blob/master/java/lang/Throwable.java#L239).

I'm curious how API 31 could have suppressed exception working even without the `suppressedExceptions` field ?

Also why suppressed exceptions are not supported when `minSdkVersion` is below 19 ?

Comment: `getSuppressed()` was added in API 19, so it makes sense that it won't work for older APIs. Did your app use `minSdkVersion: 18`? If so, I'm suprise it can compiled.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support:
> In addition to the Java 8 language features above, plugin versions 3.0.0 and later extend support for try-with-resources to all Android API levels.
Such Java 7 feature works thanks to suppressed exceptions. So I guess this API is "supported" since then. IMHO "supported" is a big word when the feature is doing nothing

Comment: Unless google has a time travel machine or patch the ROM, yes "supported" is just a fancy word at the of the day.